Data Frame .to_sql() causes an wierd error when INSERTING into SQL Server database
I have seen quite a few questions posted here regarding the error of .to_sql(). Usually are about invalid objects or inserting wrong value type. But none of them are same as mine. I got a piece of code from my coworkers which can run successfully on his desktop. But when I tried to run it, I got the following error when the code tries to use .to_sql() to insert the data into a table. Mine is complaining about the table the code writes to?

Error Message: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY104', '[HY104] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid precision value (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: SELECT [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE ([INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) OR [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_TYPE] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max))]
[parameters: ('BASE TABLE', 'VIEW', 'table_name', 'schema_name')]
(Background on this error at:
https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)

I also had another person run the same code on his PC. He got the same error as mine. Does anyone have a clue what is this error complaining about or what may cause this error.
By the way, we have the same python version: 3.9.13 and same package version:
bottleneck==1.3.4
conda==4.12.0
cython==0.29.28
matplotlib==3.5.1
numpy==1.21.5
pandas==1.4.2
pyodbc==4.0.32
python-dateutil==2.8.2
requests==2.27.1
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.7.3
seaborn==0.11.2
sphinx==4.4.0
sqlalchemy==1.4.32

We are writing to the same server and the same table.

provide your code as well

your pyodbc package is really old , update that package and try again
